# jenkins jobs failing after Github upgrade to 3.4.2

Tags: github, jenkins

Upgraded the GitHub enterprise server from version 2.22.5 to 3.4.2(latest). The github allows 2 jumps at a time during the upgrade.

Hence I upgraded from 2.22.5 to 3.1.7 and then from 3.1.7 to 3.3.7.
Now the final upgrade from 3.3.7 to 3.4.2.

I tested the Jenkins jobs at each version and it worked but failed at the final version.

Here is the error description:

> : ERROR : Received unexpected response with status code 404, when the
> expected status code was 200. Message: "{"message":"Not
> Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.4/rest"}".

Comment: I haven't used github's API, but I doubt there's enough information here.  You'll almost certainly have to do some debugging on your end to at least figure out the endpoint you're trying to use.